# Does a "willing" creature know the outcome of the spell that is being cast on them?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting

Perhaps put another way, can you lie when casting a spell on a "willing creature"? For instance, I could cast Dimension Door on myself and one willing creature. I may tell him we're going across that gorge, but in reality, we're going 500 feet up for some tasty 20d6 fall damage for both of us, because why not?

Does a willing creature know what they are subjecting themselves to specifically? Or do they merely allow a spell to be cast on them, trusting that you're going to do what you say you're going to do?

Comment: I think your example could use some work. In this limited case the creature knows the outcome of the spell right away, since he is now 500ft up in the air. Any details of the spell (targets, other parameters) might be able to be perceived by a skill check, otherwise they are unknown to everyone but the caster. Can you think of a spell that can have different results when cast on the same creature (I'm thinking of Pathfinder's prayer, which affects 'allies' and 'enemies' differently)?

Comment: @GreySage: I'm pretty sure the question's asking if they know what spell you're casting on them when the determination is made that they're willing (i.e. whether they're agreeing to be affected by the spell without necessarily knowing, or whether they know for sure what spell's being cast on them).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They just know that you say you're casting a spell on them, by default.

If you are casting a different spell, they could determine that with Intelligence/Arcana.

If you are lying about where you're going, you'd probably need to Charisma/Deception them because they might get a Wisdom/Insight check to determine your treachery. (They might get this for you casting a different spell, etc. too.)

So they "trust you," inasmuch as they want to trust you and inasmuch as their other skills don't detect your deception.

Comment: Sounds good enough to me, but do you know of any source in the books for this or is it just conjecture? A page number would be fine

Comment: You can't prove a negative. The books don't say you do know automatically, and they have skill usage like Intelligence/Arcana that describe how one might know, therefore by the inexorable march of logic rather than specific page number, you don't know.