# Can I cast Fly on my horse and then ride it?

Tags: dnd-5e, flight, mount

> You touch a willing creature. The target gains a flying
>   speed o f 60 feet for the duration. When the spell ends,
>   the target falls if it is still aloft, unless it can stop the fall.

Now, can I cast *Fly* on my horse? Can it be considered a willing creature? If so, will I be able to ride it while flying without it needing special training first?

Answer (score 19):

> can I cast Fly on my horse?

It's a creature and so is a valid target.

> Can it be considered a willing creature?

Probably; its willing to let you climb on its back, however, your DM has the final call on this. See [Can you make an unwilling creature willing? In other words, what defines “willing”?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62794/can-you-make-an-unwilling-creature-willing-in-other-words-what-defines-willin)

> If so, will I be able to ride it while flying?

Sure, why wouldn't you be able to?

Comment: *RE: "Sure, why wouldn't you be able to?"* In some editions there's a maximum weight a flying creature can carry and still fly (in *D&D 3.5* that's a light load if the creature can naturally [fly](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#fly) but up to the creature's maximum encumbrance while the subject of the spell [*fly*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/fly.htm), for instance). It might be useful to clarify the absence of such restrictions in *5E*.

Comment: Generally the rules for flying weight as suggested by Mearls is to subtract the creatures weight from its total carrying capacity in 5E and thats how much more weight it can take while flying. But since this an optional thing and so very few DMs actually track encumbrance; I think this very direct rules as written from Dale are enough to answer the question presented. Weight mechanics would be a separate question.

Comment: In our specific case, the flying creature is a mule and the riding creature is a gnome, so I think that there would be no problems with weight. My only concern was the need to train the creature before you can control it.

Comment: The carrying capacity idea makes sense if the creature is flying on its own strength (using fantasy physics), but less so when it's *magic*. With that, anything from "no extras" to "some limit based on the caster's" skill to "it's magic, so anything that can fit" seems potentially valid.

Comment: @mattdm if you are playing with the optional encumbrance rules then being overloaded progressively reduces your speed (ultimately to 0) - this affects all of your speeds, normal, fly, climb etc.

Comment: Consider that your player may need a high animal handling skill to prevent the horse from being spooked - additionally, conttolling the animal may require skill as well.

Comment: @firion If that's a concern you have, it's important to say so in the question, since we can't read minds. :) I've put it in the question for you.

Comment: @jedd.ahyoung: That's a good point. I would have suspected the mount has no idea it has a fly speed and so simply wouldn't try to use it.

Answer (score 13):

I would rule that yes you can, but you would need to train the horse to follow flying commands, and not panic. It takes time to train a horse for even basic riding. But if a player wants to invest the time, sure. Sounds awesome and fun.

Comment: Magic horse training! Start with _jump_ horse, then _fly_ horse. Eventually use _polymorph_ for easy access Pegasus!

Comment: If you've got Polymoph, why do you need a horse OR a pegasus? Grow your own dang wings!