# Does the Catnap spell affect people that are already unconscious?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, hit-points, unconscious

**Does the Catnap spell affect people that are already unconscious?**

An example:

The trusty fighter fights and takes damage, and is reduced to 0 hitpoints.   The wizard kills the bad guy(s), and stabilizes the fighter.

Now the wizard looks over his trusty fighter and casts the spell [*catnap*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/catnap) (*Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, p. 151), desiring for the fighter to wake up in 10 minutes after getting the full effect of a short rest, including a short rest's worth of healing, rather than after 1d4 hours with 1 hitpoint.

Does this work the way the wizard hopes?  Or have I misread something?

Comment: Related: [Can unconscious characters be willing?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/80393/42865)

Answer (score 5):

## Unconscious creatures are not valid targets for *catnap*

*Catnap* says:

> up to three **willing** creatures of your choice that you can see within range fall unconscious

The fighter is unconscious and **unconscious creatures are not willing**. Crawford confirms this point in regards to a [similar question about dimension door](http://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/04/19/can-you-take-a-unconscious-target-with-you-using-dimension-door/):

> Only a willing creature can travel with you via dimension door. **You can't give consent when you're unconscious.**