# Can I teleport unconcious allies with Thunder Step?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, teleportation, unconscious

Say my ally is making death saving throws, can I still teleport him with Thunder Step? Provided that he is the same size or smaller, within 5 feet of me and there is space for him where I teleport to.

> **Thunder Step:**
>   You can bring along objects as long as their weight doesn't exceed what you
>   can carry. You can also teleport one willing creature of your size or smaller who
>   is carrying gear up to its carrying capacity. The creature must be within 5 feet
>   of you when you cast this spell, and there must be an unoccupied space within
>   5 feet of your destination space for the creature to appear in; otherwise, the
>   creature is left behind.

Comment: Possibly related: [Is a dead creature's body considered an “object”?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55951/is-a-dead-creatures-body-considered-an-object)

Comment: Note that a character who is still making death saving throws is unconscious, not dead. With that in mind, does this answer your question? [Can unconscious characters be willing?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/80393/can-unconscious-characters-be-willing)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Can you make an unwilling creature willing? In other words, what defines “willing”?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62794/can-you-make-an-unwilling-creature-willing-in-other-words-what-defines-willin)

Comment: I considered this question to be not a duplicate since it requires us to establish both that an unconscious creature is "not an object" and "not willing." The latter is definitively answered elsewhere, but I'm not sure if the former has specifically been asked. (Although the way Ralph's asked this question, specifically pointing out the creature's size, does imply he or she was mainly asking about the willingness of the unconscious creature.)

Comment: Why do you think *thunder step* might or might not work? Clarifying what it is you don't understand or are uncertain about will go a long way towards getting you answers which are helpful to you (+ in the long run).

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 2):

### No, because an unconscious person is neither an object, nor willing

Unfortunately, the RAW ("rules as written") answer to your question is "no." As you stated, the rules on Thunderstep state (bold added for emphasis):

> You can bring along **objects** as long as their weight doesn't exceed what you can carry. You can also teleport **one willing creature** of your size or smaller who is carrying gear up to its carrying capacity.

So the ally must either be "objects" or "one willing creature" for you to teleport them.

### Your unconscious ally is not an "object"

Although an unconscious creature behaves much like an "object" (in that they do not move), the Dungeon Master's Guide defines an object on page 246 as (bold added):

> a discrete **inanimate** item.

And "inanimate" means more than "not moving": it means ["not alive"](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/inanimate) or ["lifeless."](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/inanimate) So **your unconscious ally is not an object** (nor a collection of objects).

### Your unconscious ally *cannot* be said to be "willing"

I'm sure that *the player controlling your ally* is totally "willing" for you to teleport their character: it might save the character's life, and is awesome to boot. But the character itself is unconscious. And it has been stated elsewhere that [an unconscious person cannot be "willing."](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/80393/can-unconscious-characters-be-willing) Even if this is something that they would consent to if they were conscious and capable, at the moment the cannot consent to anything since (PHB, p. 292, bold added)

> An unconscious creature ... is unaware of its surroundings

So an unconscious ally, who normally would be totally fine with you teleporting it, does not know you are attempting to do so or why, and thus cannot have any opinion on whether or not you should. Even if they previously gave you blanket permission to teleport them in this precise scenario, they currently are not in the state of mind to be "willing" for you to do such an action. So in this (and all other) context(s), **an unconscious creature cannot be said to be "willing."**

### A DM might let your ally *become* briefly willing

A DM might bend these rules if they want! The ability to thunderously teleport an ally to safety is really cool, and the DM could easily decide that this is permitted (perhaps declaring that the ally flits into consciousness just for a second and becomes willing). But if we're going strictly by the rules as written, then an unconscious person cannot be teleported by Thunderstep, as **an unconscious person is neither willing nor an object.**