# Does the target of Gaze of Two Minds have to remain willing?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, warlock, eldritch-invocations

So, I've figured out a possible way to use Gaze of Two Minds as a kind of scrying. So, my plan is to find a goon of some enemy, use Suggestion or just convince them to let me activate Gaze of Two Minds. Then, I'd have my allies move me away from wherever I was- and then they can attack them. They let the GOTM'd one run away- back to their base, which I would be able to see. We would basically get a spy on the inside without them even wanting to work with us. I'm wondering if the target of GOTM has to remain willing for the duration of the ability- since the target would probably no longer be willing after we started killing their friends. For reference-

> "You can use your action to touch a willing humanoid and perceive
>   through its senses until the end of your next turn. As long as the
>   creature is on the same plane of existence as you, you can use your
>   action on subsequent turns to maintain this connection, extending the
>   duration until the end of your next turn." -Player's Handbook, Part 1, Chapter 3, Page 111.

Comment: In general, you may want to give more time for other answers to show up before accepting one. While I don't mind the karma, you may get something different that is better...I have been known to be wrong :)

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the advice- I'm new here, still trying to get the hang of things.

Comment: No worries! You've been asking some interesting questions - just give time for answers to come in and enjoy the information :)

Comment: Not an answer, but you should "ask your DM", as usual. The term "willing" isn't defined in the rules. Is a creature under the effect of Suggestion "willing"? You "touch a willing humanoid" - willing what, to be touched? Does they have to know how the spell works in order to maintain the connection? Et cetera

Comment: related, [what defines a willing creature](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62794/can-you-make-an-unwilling-creature-willing-in-other-words-what-defines-willin)

Comment: Something interesting to note- nowhere in the description for Gaze of Two Minds does it say that the willing humanoid is _aware_ of the connection.  Does a creature still count as willing if it doesn't know the link still exists?  My DM instincts say "hell no," but my player side invented a table rule that we still use today called Implied Consent:  Until someone says "No," assume the answer is "Yes."  Remember, the willing creature presumably said "Yes" once, so it ultimately boils down to whether they have to say "Yes" every round.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## RAW is maybe, but intent is likely No

Although the text only includes the term "Willing" at the beginning, you are effectively continuing the Gaze each round. If the target is ever no longer willing, it seems that it would end the effect because they no longer let your mind link continue. I think that this is the intent of "willing".

However, the ambiguity of the language does leave the door open for the example you've given. Suggestion lasts up to 8 hours, but if you are looking at ending it early or wanting to do it longer this becomes an interesting test of Gaze of Two Minds.

Remember, you also are blinded and deafened to your own surroundings at this time. That leaves you in a pretty vulnerable state that could balance a ruling allowing GoTM to remain after a creature is no longer willing.

Answer (score 6):

Rules As Written this seems legal, although this is the sort of thing where a DM might reasonably issue a different ruling.

This seems needlessly convoluted, though. If you get the minion to fail against your Suggestion spell, you could just suggest that they give you a tour of their base using your Gaze Of Two Minds ability. For that matter you could just suggest that they tell you all about their base. ("I suggest that you answer all my questions truthfully and completely.") That way you wouldn't have an enemy running back to base to raise the alarm about your group.

Comment: A ruling is not a house rule.  What you are referring to (given the lack of clarity in the text) is the DM making a ruling.  Subtle distinction, but one worth making (in this edition in particular).