# Can a creature use Legendary Resistance to succeed on the saving throw against a Scrying spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters, saving-throw, divination

My players recently decided that they would like to cast the [*scrying*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/scrying) spell on a creature that has the Legendary Resistance trait.

Does the Legendary Resistance trait function outside of combat?

My major concern is that the creature wouldn't necessarily know it was being scryed on in order to use the resistance to avoid it.  In combat, a creature could see a (for example) *fireball* coming and decide to avoid it, but with no indicator at all that a spell was targeting the creature, it is less clear to me.

Comment: Related on [Do creatures with Legendary Resistance know what they're making a saving throw against when they choose whether to use it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77911)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

#### Legendary Resistance can be used against any saving throw, at the DM's discretion.

RAW, there is nothing to prevent the creature, such as an [adult red dragon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/adult-red-dragon) (MM, pg. 98), from using legendary resistance against a *scrying* spell. Everything we need to know about legendary resistance is contained in its description:

> ***Legendary Resistance (3/day).*** If the dragon fails a saving throw, it can choose to succeed instead.

The *only* condition for using it is stated: "if the dragon fails a saving throw". Since *scrying* triggers a saving throw, the dragon first can make the saving throw; on a failure, the dragon can use legendary resistance.

[This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/77919/62294) gives a good perspective on legendary resistance that may help realign your perspective of the feature:

> **Legendary Resistance is a DM tool, not an ability that a monster chooses to use.**
>
> I think it's best to treat Legendary Resistance as a game-mechanical way for the DM to make a climactic battle entertaining. A monster with Legendary Resistance doesn't choose whether to use it or not; the DM chooses whether having the monster make a saving throw will make the battle more entertaining or not. It's (presumably) available so that epic monsters that are typically fought solo aren't quickly overcome by a couple of effects that require saving throws.

Ultimately, it is up to the DM to use it or not, but the DM would be entirely within RAW to use it against *scrying*. Personally, the party *scrying* on a big bad is a treasure trove of plot development material, so I would be inclined to allow it to push the plot forward.

Comment: "Personally, the party scrying on a big bad is a treasure trove of plot development material, so I would be inclined to allow it to push the plot forward."

Though sometimes difficulty with the scrying can result in in plot hooks too, if it causes the party to seek out how to overcome whatever is foiling their attempts. See Vaarsuvius’s story in the *Don’t Split the Party* arc of *Order of the Stick* for a particularly frightening example.

Comment: Great answer - I'll accept it unless something else amazing comes in.  In my case, I was looking to see if I had handled a situation that happened last weekend correctly.  I chose to let them successfully scry - and discovering that their foe was an elder brain was certainly the correct plot-development choice, if on shaky grounds, mechanically.

Comment: @Tal I'd like to note that legendary resistance says the dragon *can* choose to succeed, but doesn't have to, so you're ruling was 100% consistent with RAW.

Comment: "Though sometimes difficulty with the scrying can result in in plot hooks too" - Or can be a good pre-fight strategy for the party, if they're inclined to metagame.  Burn their three legendary resistances from safely afar, then move in for the kill.

Comment: The answer you quote does not cite *anything* to support that claim. And the description of the feature clearly conflicts with what you say (it literally says that the creature chooses). **Please back your answer up.** Maybe there is a published adventure with relevant GM advice?

Comment: As described in my answer, I called it a perspective. Not rules, just a perspective. My answer is backed up by experience - experience that seems to have been quite well received, both on this answer and the one I quote.

Comment: I could cite the rule about the DM being in charge over the rules, but I’m not sure it’s relevant since what I suggest is entirely consistent with the rules.

Comment: Something to remember about the spell is that it can be seen. On a failed save, the spell creates an Invisible sensor within 10 feet of the target. . A creature that can see Invisible Objects sees the sensor as a luminous orb about the size of your fist.

Instead of targeting a creature, you can choose a location you have seen before as the target of this spell. When you do, the sensor appears at that location and doesn't move.

So while not making the save it is very possible that the elder brain was aware of the scry and can then reverse scry to see them.