# Can a creature without its own will (e.g. zombies, golems) be a "willing creature" when controlled?

Tags: dnd-5e, undead, targeting, spellcasting, constructs

In D&D 5e it appears that **willing creature** is defined by consent.

Zombies, skeletons, and golems all essentially have no will, but while they are under the control of someone, can they be **willing creatures** for the purposes of spells?

For example, could a necromancer bring along her zombie minions when using the **teleport** spell?

Comment: Related: "[Can you make an unwilling creature willing? In other words, what defines “willing”?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62794)"

Comment: @Medix2 vampires and liches can certainly be willing. I've edited the question to be clearer.

Comment: I think removing the assumption about zombies/skeletons/golems would just be best. There's no real reason to care about whether they're willing when *not* being controlled when this question is specifically about what happens *while* they are controlled. Basically, I feel it would be better to leave that alone to be its own question; something like "Can a zombie be a willing target of a spell?"

Comment: Related: "[Does a willing creature know the outcome of a spell that is being used on him?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/60108/does-a-willing-creature-know-the-outcome-of-a-spell-that-is-being-used-on-him)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## It's unclear

'Willing' is [not defined anywhere in the 5e rules](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/62795/14848). That means the game thinks that the word should be used in the manner of 'natural language'.  That *does not* work for terms like 'willing' (or 'target' for that matter), because the people writing the rules are game designers for Wizards of the Coast (viz. people at the same company and in related roles to the people who write stuff for Magic:The Gathering.  For reference, *that* franchise's current explanation of what a 'target' is is rule 115 and is a little over two pages long) and so have a different definition of those sorts of words than the average non-game-playing person, and furthermore for 'willing' in particular because the philosophy of consent is super complicated *anyways* and there *is* no single consistent 'natural language' meaning of the word, even more than for most words--q.v. [philosophic research into voluntarism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/decision-capacity/#RevVol), and/or [coersion](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/coercion/).

Consequently, any sort of edge-case here is fundamentally beyond the scope of RPGing to determine-- the designers erroneously left out a definition for 'willing' and your group has to add one to make the game playable when what 'willing' means comes up in play, which it will almost certainly do in nearly every campaign.

I will leave the philosophical analysis for discussion elsewhere; you could ask about it [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/), potentially.  That said, let's discuss the mechanical implications.

1. Unlike in older editions, no creatures in 5e have non-abilities.  Skeletons and zombies and golems are, thus, typically just as sentient (i.e. possessed of charisma, intelligence, and wisdom) as other beings, they just are also frequently described as mindless automatons, which is pretty weird.  Thus it is unclear if the problem you are describing actually exists; it may be appropriate, depending on how you rule the animation works in each case, to treat them similarly to a dominated or allied creature, assuming you've already worked out what 'willing' means in those contexts.
2. If you rule that skeletons et. al. aren't or can't be willing from the perspective of their controllers, then those controllers are unable to mount them.  This means no riding skeleton horses; doing so becomes impossible:

   > A willing creature that is at least one size larger than you and that has an appropriate anatomy can serve as a mount

   ([source](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MountedCombat), also PHB p. 198)
3. If you rule that skeletons et. al. are willing for whatever their creator/controller wants, the game works fine and seems normal.
4. If you rule that skeletons et. al. *could* be willing but *aren't* in the case of undead if you are their creator/controller because they hate you and want you to die the game [gets weird](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/130134/how-can-i-best-narrate-the-position-of-an-unhidden-invisible-skeleton/130151) but still works okay and is fun but very grim.

Comment: "A willing creature that is at least one size larger than you and that has an appropriate anatomy can serve as a mount" That is the kind of rule I was looking for! What page and book is that from?

Comment: @NathanHinchey Well, I took it from the https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MountedCombat basic rules but I'm 90% sure it's also worded identically in the combat section of the PHB.

Comment: Yep, it's identical to what's printed in my copy of the PHB on page 198. I think that gives a clear case of the word "willing" being used about a horse. So the definition of willing includes a beast that cannot understand what a spell is, and that you're controlling with physical reins. So it seems very reasonable that a friendly creature you are mind-controlling counts.